# Backgrid.js: Getting selectedmodels() attributes

Tags: backbone.js, backgrid

I am trying to add a shortlist button to a datagrid (using backgrid.js http://backgridjs.com/)

What i want is the shortlist button takes the id's of all selectedmodels and save them in database.

If i do this this.model.get('id') it takes the id of current row but i want to take the id's of checked check-box's.

When I look closer and use "grid.getSelectedModels", this call returns an empty array.

So how can i get the id's of selectedmodels?

Answer (score 0):

The only way grid#getSelectedModels is empty is when you are not using SelectAllHeaderCell in combination with SelectRowCell. Is this the case?

Comment: I am using it like this cell: "select-row",
    headerCell: "select-all"

Comment: Then it should work. If it doesn't and you can reproduce it, it may be a bug and you can file a ticket.

Comment: If you get the array returned from getSelectedModels, that's an array of models and they all have an id.

Comment: Make sure you are using the latest version of Backgrid too.